# Dynamically assign class to paragraph

Tags: javascript, html, css, dynamic

How do you assign a class dynamically to a paragraph (via javascript/CSS) IF the paragraph contains the wording "Time Recorded:"?

You'll notice that I have manually assigned the paragraph with class *class="dyncontent"*.

However, I'd like to dynamically assign this class to any paragraph tag which contain the words "Time Recorded:".

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (document.all || document.getElementById){ //if IE4 or NS6+
document.write('<style type="text/css">')
document.write('.dyncontent{display:none;}')
document.write('</style>')
}
</script>
<div class="right">
<ul>
<li class="say agent public">
<p>Description line 1</p>
<p class="dyncontent">Time Recorded: 5MIN(S)</p>
<p>Another description line</p>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use jQuery:

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 $(function(){
      $("p:contains('Time Recorded:')").addClass('dyncontents');
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm restricted to use CSS/JavaScript only.

Comment: Jquery is a JS library. The Library is Javascript but Jquery code uses methods not available without the lib. Not to argue symantics

Comment: Thank you - didn't know. You can tell I'm new to this :P

Comment: @AlexReynolds I agree its a JS library but still written in JS. Well if the user can use Javascript he would probably be able to use jQuery as well...

Comment: This works a treat. Just had to update the 'dyncontents' to 'dyncontent' - THANK YOU !! :)

Comment: This is the beauty of jQuery that you often can write very elegant and simple to read code. Great it works for you!

Comment: @jtheman no I agree in most situations you can use Jquery. I tend to see it as a crutch because many people would use it just for 2-4 lines of code on the page, but that's my opinion and def doesn't mean it's right

Comment: @AlexReynolds Yes thats true but when you develop your code you often need to add more functions and then the ease of a great library is often much at hand. Pure JS is so much harder to read as I see it, and a goal for me is to write code that easily can be reused, therefore I argue for jQuery instead of basic JS mostly but with possible exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

`$("p").each(function(ele) {if (this.html().indexOf('TimeRecorded') > 1) {$(this).addClass('dyncontent'))}});`

Answer (score 1):

I'd do indexOf because it will match easier than innerText

```
var allP = document.getElementsByTagName('p'),
    pLength = allP.length;
while(pLength--){
    if(allP[pLength].innerHTML.indexOf('Time Recorded') != -1){
    allP[pLength].addClass('dycontents');
    }
}
```

To explain: first you get all the `<p>` in the document. Then you loop through them. If any of them contain text of Time Recorded you add your class to it.

Comment: As a note if you're not using Jquer yyou'll have to add you class using `appP[pLength].class = 'dycontents' or even more complicated if your elem might already have a class cuz you don't want to overwrite the current class.

Answer (score -1):

**The following is solution without Jquery**

```
o = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

    for (i = 0; i < o.length; i++) {
        if (o[i].innerText.indexOf('Time Recorded:') != -1) {
        o[i].className = 'theClassYouWant'; 
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think they're asking for a substring match.

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard Please Edit my answer, because I don't know how to figure it with the pattern 'Time recorded:*'

Comment: I have added this within the <script> tags in the html but didn't work. Unless I have done this wrong, it doesn't appear to be working :(

Comment: @user1684300: o[i].class should have been o[i].className.  You may also want to use += ' theClassYouWant' to add the class instead of replacing.